# How the logical operators works in java?

Tags: java, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I executed the below java code in IDE. the first sysout prints false. where as second sysout prints true. Some websites says because of operator precedence this occurs.

```
System.out.println(false && true | true);
boolean a = false && true;
boolean b = true;
System.out.println(a | b);
```

can someone help me to understand ?

I executed on the IDE, false && true | true prints false , where as (false && true) | true prints true. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Do you understand why `false && (true | true)` would be false? Because that's how `false && true | true` is resolved. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: The code is not executed left to right: it is executed in the order of the operator precedence table https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @cup order of execution and order of precedence are separate things. Expressions *are* evaluated left-to-right.